# Phaser, расставить объекты на сцене

Tags: html5, phaser-framework

Есть спрайт, его надо расставить на ~30 позиций, как "размножить" и указать для каждого свои координаты? Использую phaser.js

Comment: таки а что не получается? делаете цикл на 30 итераций и рисуете на позиции + смещение..... каждый объект заносится в массив........ у вас что-то есть, наработка, или это абстрактный вопрос? Потому что на данный момент он никак не связан с `phaser`, а просто с базой логики и программирования

Comment: не заметил ошибку и продолжительное время не мог исправить. Вроде получилось..

Comment: в следующий раз, если возникнут проблемы по чему-либо конкретному - добавляйте в вопрос имеющийся код и описывайте на нём что не получается и что пытаетесь сделать. Иначе он абсолютно абстрактен и несколько бесполезен